# How to make the first item of a ListView to be selected as default at startup?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

There is a ListView in my App and the ListView has a selector. I want to make the first item of this ListView to be selected **as default** at the very **startup of App**, How? Can anyone give some tips? THX a lot.

Comment: Down vote for not providing some snippet to help you out, Without looking into your code SO can't guess where are you stuck.

Comment: See also for a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409421/listview-list-item-selection-and-initial-setting-custom-made-items

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this by

```
yourListView.setSelection(0);
yourListView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: @ChiragPatel will u please help me on this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099756/default-selection-of-a-row-in-the-listview-and-highlist-the-slected-row-android

Comment: @ChiragPatel Can we select List automatically into string variable please help me how can i select list item with the help of String value

Answer (score 11):

```
yourlist.setItemChecked(position,true)
```

Answer (score 4):

This work for me. I hope this will help you. :)

```
 @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    // do someting...
    if(position == 0){
        mListView.performItemClick(convertView, 0, 0);
    }

 }
```

now i found another good way to implement this.

- Firstly,you should set ListView **android:choiceMode=singleChoice**
- Secondly,just go ahead as follow,

  ```
      int defaultPositon = 0;
      int justIgnoreId = 0;
      mListView.setItemChecked(defaultPositon, true);
      mListView.performItemClick(mListView.getSelectedView(), defaultPositon, justIgnoreId);
  ```

Comment: This works. One problem solved, now next one: selected item is not getting highlighted. WTF Android!

Answer (score 2):

```
//put the below code in get view function 
if(position==0)
{
    convertView.setSelected(true); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work as we have given 0 index of array to listView

```
ListView.setSelection(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an `onItemClickListener` then use this snippet, filling in the appropriate values:

```
listView.performItemClick(View view, int position, long id);
```

[See the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#performItemClick%28android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29) for further detail.

Comment: Maybe you should provide some code in you question to show us how you are attempting it.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `listview.setSelection(0);`. Just make sure you are calling this after poplulating your `List`. If you call it before populating your `List` it will not work, because it won't have any data at that time.

Comment: I think your answer is suitable and helpful, but it doesn't work when I put it in my code where in think the list have been populated.Maybe something wrong in other place of the code......

Comment: It would be better if you can post code how you are writing it.

Comment: @LalitPoptani can u help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099756/default-selection-of-a-row-in-the-listview-and-highlight-the-slected-row-android/18099844?noredirect=1#comment26498081_18099844

Answer (score 1):

Below solution works for me:

Setting background/View Id on get View & using the setOnItemClickListener of the List View

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)
                ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);
    }
    ListItem m = items.get(position);

    if (m != null) {

        TextView txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        txt.setText(m.Item);

    }

    // set selected item
    LinearLayout ActiveItem = (LinearLayout) v;
    v.setId(position);
    if (position == GetDeviceDetails.selectedsize)
    {
        ActiveItem.setBackgroundColor(0xFF7F8184);
    }
    return v;
}
```

In the Activity on Create :

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position, long id) {
                    adapter.findViewById(GetDeviceDetails.selectedsize).setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFF);
                    GetDeviceDetails.selectedsize = position;
                    adapter.findViewById(position).setBackgroundColor(0xFF7F8184);
                    Log.d("Selected Id", "" + v.getId());
                    Log.d("find Selected Id", "" + adapter.findViewById(0));
                }
            });
    listView1.setSelection(0);
    listView1.setItemChecked(0, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you want to click it to get additional event handling done:

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(position, null, null).performClick();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it like this.

```
//set list adapter, then
lv.setItemChecked(1, true);//position 1
lv.setSelection(1);//position 1
```

Update XML layout with single choice.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_background"
    android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1dip" >
</ListView>
```

and set listview background XML as list_item_background.xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_default"   android:state_activated="false"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**THIS WORKS FOR ME.You have to make custom adapter.**

```
     First Create Modal Class

        public class FilterBean {

         String filter_catagory;
                 boolean isSelected;

            public boolean isSelected() {
                return isSelected;
            }

            public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
                isSelected = selected;
            }

          public String getFilter_catagory() {
                return filter_catagory;
            }

            public void setFilter_catagory(String filter_catagory) {
                this.filter_catagory = filter_catagory;
            }

        }


    In Adapter Class

    @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.size_name_indicator, null);
            txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.key_textView);
            txt.setText(getItem(position).getFilter_catagory());

            if(getItem(position).isSelected()){
                txt.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
            }else {

                txt.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
            }


            return convertView;
        }

     public void updateNameBean(String key,boolean checked)
        {

            for(int i=0;i<getCount();i++)
            {
                FilterBean filterBean =  getItem(i);
                if(filterBean.getFilter_catagory().equals(key))
                {
                    filterBean.setSelected(checked);
                }else {
                    filterBean.setSelected(false);
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

In Filter Activity or Fragment

 filter_listView.setAdapter(filterNameAdapter);
               filterNameAdapter.updateNameBean(filterNameAdapter.getItem(0).getFilter_catagory(),true);
        filter_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                String key = filterNameAdapter.getItem(position).getFilter_catagory();
                filterNameAdapter.updateNameBean(filterNameAdapter.getItem(position).getFilter_catagory(),true);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used data binding to solve this,

using the following codebehind:

```
private List<Unit> _units;
private Unit _selectedUnit;
public Unit selectedUnit{
  get{
    if (_selectedUnit is null){
      return _units.Count > 0 ? _units[0] : null;
    }else{
      return _selectedUnit;
    }
  }
  set{
    if (_selectedUnit != value){
      _selectedUnit = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("selectedUnit");
    }
  }
}
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName){
  var changed = PropertyChanged;
  if (changed != null){
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

and XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding units}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding selectedUnit, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(position == 0){
        // This is the first item, you need to select this
        //rowview which u inflate under getview 
        rowView.performClick();

    }
```

i think this will help you . it works for me

Comment: this will fail because position 0 can call n number of time when listview will get scroll.