# Highlight the first element in a listview when it's shown

Tags: android, listview, element, highlight

I have a listview.
On each element of the listview you can touch and it triggers something (ie a toast).
Each time you touch on any element it must remain highlighted.

I want that the first element in the listview to appear highlighted by default the first time the listview is showed, this is when you launch the app.

Right now I have all working except the highlight in the first element the first time. I mean, the element is even triggered but is not highlighted when you launch the app.

Any ideas?

I've tried a lot of thiings that I've read on stackoverflow but non worked and I think should be something very common.

I've tried setSelection, setSelected, getting the view.....

I though it worked like the spinner but it's not.

Thanks a lot guys!!

You can check the class code here --> http://goo.gl/ndY0Ni

If any of you want to try it, I've made a simpler example --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83259317/main.rar

**SOLUTION: Thanks to @Jiahao to provide a solution.**

I've made a little proyect in order to you check it out --> http://goo.gl/35s5Dc

Comment: Read at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577568/how-to-make-the-first-item-of-a-listview-to-be-selected-as-default-at-startup

Comment: @PankajKumar If you realize, I've already answer in that topic. That doesn't work for me and almost anyone there.

Comment: @RushabhPatel You can check the class code here --> http://goo.gl/ndY0Ni

Comment: @Jahnux73 I've tried things like setItemChecked, setSelection, setSelected....

Comment: Try it yourself -> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83259317/main.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetItemChecked works for the list. The problem is when your row view is not an instance of Checkable, it is not shown.

Instead, a stated callled "Activated" will be marked.

The easiest solution is customize the rowView to show the state Activated:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed"/>
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed"/>
    <item
        android:state_activated="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/listview_selector_pressed"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@android:color/white" />
</selector>
```

Comment: Maybe this add some clue but it's not working. I've added the pressed, selected, active, activated.... a lot of states to my xml and in my activity I've try with setSelected(true), setActivated(true), setItemchecked.....

Nothing is working.

Comment: Yes!! This is it!!

To all of you guys, be sure of you minSDK level when using selectingItem, and yes, a third state on the xml is needed.

I have updated a little proyect to you guys check it out --> http://goo.gl/35s5Dc

Answer (score 0):

To set a ListView Item as highlighted you use this code:

```
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); // Highlight one at a time.
getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
```

Where position is the number of the ListItem you want to hightlight, So to highlight the first item you do:

```
  getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
  getListView().setItemChecked(0, true);
```

This is assuming you are using a ListActivity. (If not just call the methods on the actual ListView Object).

Comment: thanks for answering. I've already tried this before and is not working. I've added a code url above in the main message.

Comment: I don't understnd why you are inflating  the layout from the activity and not in onCreateView()? Is the ListView that you are trying to modify in the R.layout.products_fragment layout?

Comment: I've always seen that they used the onCreteView (http://goo.gl/lrQuQJ) to return the view of the fragment layout.

Yes, the listView element I'm trying to highlight is in that layout. (mProductsListView)

Comment: Can you try to inflate the layout in onCreateView()? Put this in onCreateView: View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.products_fragment, container, false); mProductListView = v.findViewById(R.id.products_listview); return v;

Comment: I did it (I had to make a casting to ListView to the sedond line) and it's working the same way than before from my point.

Comment: You can try it yourself --> https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83259317/main.rar