# automatically select first item in list view, and do some other things being called in OnItemClickListener() without having to click

Tags: android, listview

total noob to android and java here.

I found some code on github for connecting a USB GPS device with a u-blox chip. it is here: https://github.com/mikey0000/Ublox-GPS-receiver-android   (It took me about 2 days to figure out how to compile this, so yes I am that much of a noob).

I have the device connected in a car android unit, and I'd like it to automatically connect when it boots.

I would like help with automatically selecting the first item in the ListView. I believe the code where this might be do-able is in DeviceListActivity.java:

```
package com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbDevice;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TwoLineListItem;

import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.CdcAcmSerialDriver;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.ProbeTable;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialDriver;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialPort;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.driver.UsbSerialProber;
import com.hoho.android.usbserial.util.HexDump;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import src.com.hoho.android.usbserial.examples.BackgroundService;

/**
 * Shows a {@link ListView} of available USB devices.
 *
 * @author mike wakerly (opensource@hoho.com)
 */
public class DeviceListActivity extends Activity {

    private final String TAG = DeviceListActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private UsbManager mUsbManager;
    private ListView mListView;
    private TextView mProgressBarTitle;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private UsbSerialProber prober;

    private static final int MESSAGE_REFRESH = 101;
    private static final long REFRESH_TIMEOUT_MILLIS = 5000;

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_REFRESH:
                    refreshDeviceList();
                    //mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MESSAGE_REFRESH, REFRESH_TIMEOUT_MILLIS);
                    break;
                default:
                    super.handleMessage(msg);
                    break;
            }
        }

    };

    private List<UsbSerialPort> mEntries = new ArrayList<UsbSerialPort>();
    private ArrayAdapter<UsbSerialPort> mAdapter;

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView textViewItem;
        TextView textViewItem2;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mUsbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.deviceList);
        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mProgressBarTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressBarTitle);

        ProbeTable customTable = new ProbeTable();
        customTable.addProduct(0x1546, 0x01a7, CdcAcmSerialDriver.class);
        prober = new UsbSerialProber(customTable);

        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<UsbSerialPort>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_2, mEntries) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null){
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.two_list_item, null);

                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                    holder.textViewItem2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                } else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(position);
                final UsbSerialDriver driver = port.getDriver();
                final UsbDevice device = driver.getDevice();

                final String title = String.format("Vendor %s Product %s",
                        HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getVendorId()),
                        HexDump.toHexString((short) device.getProductId()));
                holder.textViewItem.setText(title);

                final String subtitle = driver.getClass().getSimpleName();
                holder.textViewItem2.setText(subtitle);

                return convertView;
            }

        };
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Pressed item " + position);
                if (position >= mEntries.size()) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "Illegal position.");
                    return;
                }

                final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(position);
                mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
                showConsoleActivity(port);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
    }

    private void refreshDeviceList() {
        showProgressBar();

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<UsbSerialPort>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<UsbSerialPort> doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Refreshing device list ...");
                SystemClock.sleep(1000);

                final List<UsbSerialDriver> drivers =
                        prober.findAllDrivers(mUsbManager);

                final List<UsbSerialPort> result = new ArrayList<UsbSerialPort>();
                for (final UsbSerialDriver driver : drivers) {
                    final List<UsbSerialPort> ports = driver.getPorts();
                    Log.d(TAG, String.format("+ %s: %s port%s",
                            driver, Integer.valueOf(ports.size()), ports.size() == 1 ? "" : "s"));
                    result.addAll(ports);
                }

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<UsbSerialPort> result) {
                mEntries.clear();
                mEntries.addAll(result);
                mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mProgressBarTitle.setText(
                        String.format("%s device(s) found",Integer.valueOf(mEntries.size())));
                hideProgressBar();
                Log.d(TAG, "Done refreshing, " + mEntries.size() + " entries found.");
            }

        }.execute((Void) null);
    }

    private void showProgressBar() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBarTitle.setText(R.string.refreshing);
    }

    private void hideProgressBar() {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    private void showConsoleActivity(UsbSerialPort port) {
        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BackgroundService.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, startIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        mUsbManager.requestPermission(port.getDriver().getDevice(), pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Started Background Service for GPS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //SerialConsoleActivity.show(this, port);
    }

}
```

Is anyone able to help? I haven't even the first clue where I could go about implementing this. TIA.

EDIT: So it looks like

```
mListView.setSelection(0);
```

is the way to go however using

```
mListView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

as well seems to make it crash.

Any idea how I can do the rest of what setOnItemClickListener is doing after automatically selecting the item in the list?

Something like:

```
mListView.setSelection(0);
final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(0);
mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
showConsoleActivity(port);
```

?

Apologies for the earlier ambiguity, but what I wanted this app to do was to do what it does already without me having to tap \ click on anything i.e. on boot automatically select the USB GPS chip that is plugged in so I'd like it not to use the OnItemClickListener or automate that part alternatively. I don't really want the app to sit there waiting for input since the car unit loads all sorts on boot and I keep missing the screen where it prompts as per current behaviour. Hope that's a bit clearer. Thanks for the help so far. Totally new to java and android as you can likely tell haha.

Update: See my answer. Sorry I wasn't clear with my original question. Thanks to everyone for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Figured it out in the end. I was after a PerformItemClick() - my question was originally ambiguous in setting out what I was trying to do so apologies if anyone lost out on the answer.

Anyway to get this app to automatically choose the connected USB GPS adapter without my having to click on the list I added the following:

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int mActivePosition = 0;
            mListView.performItemClick(
            mListView.getChildAt(mActivePosition),
            mActivePosition,
            mListView.getAdapter().getItemId(mActivePosition));
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            //startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);

        }
    }, 2000);
```

after

```
mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
```

and it seemed to do the trick. I also added the intent in there to go to the home page - this seems to help the unit (a car android unit) boot more quickly and call some apps I have configured to load on boot more quickly too.

Thanks to everyone for the answers - sorry I wasn't originally very clear with the question. Hopefully it might be useful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this setSelection api to true

```
mListView.setSelection(0);
mListView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

for more answers you can check this [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577568/how-to-make-the-first-item-of-a-listview-to-be-selected-as-default-at-startup), you just need to figure it out where you need to put this code snippet in your code, depending on your needs.

Comment: now to figure out where to put it. my humble apologies, but I really don't know where to start. I'll try some trial and error...

Comment: @cantcode most probably it should be after setAdapter line

Comment: please accept the answer if it worked ...@cantcode Thanks

Comment: @Vivek  yes i tried that. it crashes. would it be somewhere in the setOnItemClickListener perhaps? Just reading through the link from JNI_OnLoad at the moment. Thank you anyway..

Comment: @JNI_OnLoad seems to crash the app when testing

Comment: @cantcode, can you put your error msg in your question, but i am sure that you should not put this on setOnItemClickListener as it will only get fired once you clicked any item

Comment: @JNI_OnLoad just get unfortunately serial example has stopped. not sure how to debug or get more info out since the usb is used by the device (so can't adb at the same time). sorry i really am a noob.
Just using mListView.setSelection(0) ; doesn't seem to crash it, but I need (I think) to call:

Comment: (continued...)                                                                                                                                    final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(position);
                mHandler.removeMessages(MESSAGE_REFRESH);
                showConsoleActivity(port);                                                                       

afterwards (I think), and really not sure how to - compiler doesn't like final UsbSerialPort port = mEntries.get(position);   if I just copy and paste

Answer (score 1):

it is very simple:
Array index start from zero so you set selected item from it index like this:
 `mListView.setSelection(0) ;`

and this like put after this line :  `mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);`