# List selector appears after itemclick. How to make it appear on the first item as soon as the listview is loaded?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I currently have a sliding menu fragment in an activity and the listview in the fragment has a selector.

[image: listview in fragment]

The issue i am facing is I want the selector to appear when the menu is opened showing the first item to be selected.But I am unable to get it. It appears when i perform the item click.  I am using an ArrayAdapter populating it with a string array:

```
    final ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);
        String[] drawerOptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_options);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.simple_list_item_1_white, drawerOptions);

 listView.setAdapter(adapter);
 listView.performItemClick(listView.getChildAt(0), 0, 0);
```

I have tried the methods mentioned in this post :[How to make the first item of a ListView to be selected as default at startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577568/how-to-make-the-first-item-of-a-listview-to-be-selected-as-default-at-startup)
still no result. My list selector code:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/menu_arrow"
    android:width="18dp"
    android:height="36dp"
    android:top="5dp"/>

<item android:top="0dp" android:left="5dp" android:bottom="0dp" android:right="0dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you show the code on where you tried the answers mentioned in the post

Comment: I added this after the setadapter()
 listView.performItemClick(listView.getChildAt(0), 0, 0);