# How to make the first item of a Custom ListView to be selected as default

Tags: android, listview

How to make the first item of a Custom ListView to be selected as default

```
lvModifierSet.setAdapter(modifierSetListAdapter);
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                ModifierSet modifierSet = modifierSets.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(context, modifierSet.getModifier_set_name(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
lvModifierSet.setOnItemClickListener(onItemClickListener);
```

This is my custom adapter

```
public class ModifierSetListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ModifierSet> {

    private Context context;
    private int resourceLayout;
    private List<ModifierSet> modifierSets;

    public ModifierSetListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<ModifierSet> modifierSets) {
        super(context, resource, modifierSets);
        this.context = context;
        resourceLayout = resource;
        this.modifierSets = modifierSets;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            view = vi.inflate(resourceLayout, null);
        }

        ModifierSet modifierSet = modifierSets.get(position);

        TextView tvModifierName = view.findViewById(R.id.modifier_set_tv_modifier_name);
        tvModifierName.setText(modifierSet.getModifier_set_name());

        return view;

    }

}
```

I am tried below 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577568/how-to-make-the-first-item-of-a-listview-to-be-selected-as-default-at-startup)

Comment: make a loop till your array and make selected like  for (int i = 0; i < heightpojo.getRecords().size(); i++) {
                            if (heightpojo.getRecords().get(i).getHid().compareToIgnoreCase(HEIGHT_NAME) == 0) {
                                System.out.println("CAST HEIGHT_NAME " + HEIGHT_NAME + "");
                                spfoot.setSelection(i);
                            }
                        }

Comment: look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577568/how-to-make-the-first-item-of-a-listview-to-be-selected-as-default-at-startup

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Check position 0 in adapter

set default textColor

```
tvModifierName.setTextColor(Your Color) ;
```

//now check position 0

```
 if (position ==0){
    tvModifierName.setTextColor(Your Color) ;
    or set backGround
    tvModifierName.setBackgroundColor(Your Color) ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a selector for your listview? If not you need to create a selector xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/default_color" />
</selector>
```

Then add it as background to your list:

```
<ListView>
  ...  
    android:background="@drawable/selector"
  ...
</ListView>
```

Then it should work with the method from the link you saw